# journalctl does not provide colored output

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, journalctl

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04, and journalctl will not provide colored output for my logs. I verified, and those logs do have colored output if not piped through journalctl. I configured my terminal as `xterm-256color`. I have tried the following:

1. I tried applying -a option to journalctl.
2. I tried setting `SYSTEMD_COLORS=true`.
3. I tried setting `SYSTEMD_COLORS=256`.
4. I tried applying `-o cat` option to journalctl.

I know that there are other ways to pipe the output through other log colorizers such as lolcat and ccze, to mention a few. However, I don't understand why it is not possible to use journalctl colorized if there are options that support it.

Answer (score 1):

install ccze

```
apt install ccze
```

then use it like

```
journalctl -fu serviceName | ccze
```

Comment: On RHEL the output is put in a buffer; you might need to see all the use cases in `man ccze`. I solved using `journalctl -u serviceName | ccze -A`